# Schedule cron event from widget

Tags: customization, widgets, hooks, cron

Can I use [wp_schedule_event()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) to set up a cron job from within a widget?

I tried, but I can't make it work, The problem seems to be the $hook parameter. The function I'm trying to hook is located within the widget class so my guess is that WP can't find it.

neither of these work:

```
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_widget_cron');
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', array(&$this, 'my_widget_cron'));
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wp_schedule_event` takes a hook as parameter, not a function. Try:

```
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_daily_event');

add_action('my_daily_event', array(&$this, 'my_widget_cron'));

if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_daily_event' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_daily_event')
}
```

If you remove the widget from the sidebar, the cron will still continue to run.
You can run the following code (outside of the widget class) to clear it:

```
if ( !is_active_widget('your_widget_callback_function') && wp_next_scheduled( 'my_daily_event' ) ) {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_daily_event');
}
```

Comment: thanks! now it works :) I have one more question: If I remove the widget from the sidebar, will the cron still continue to run?

Comment: Yes, it will continue to run. You will have to clear it. I updated my answer with a sample code.